# Cat is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to set up webpack on a Windows 10 machine, and when trying to print out the package.json file via the command `cat package.json` I've got the error message `cat is not recognized as an internal or external command.`

How do I make this work?

Comment: `cat` is a linux command

Comment: use powershell and `cat` will work

Comment: using cat in powershell is not working for me, do you have to install another package

Answer (score 3):

See this article: https://superuser.com/questions/434870/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-command-cat

Apparently the equivalent is `type package.json` on Windows.